# Working around multiple inheritance in Java

Tags: java, inheritance, multiple-inheritance

I have the following hierarchy of base classes:

- `Index` (Abstract)

  - `RootIndex`
  - `AbstractSubIndex` (Abstract)

Then I have two more classes:

- `KPI`, which should inherit `AbstractSubIndex`, as well as add functionality unique to itself;
- `SubIndex`, which should inherit the functionality of both `AbstractSubIndex` as well as the functionality in `RootIndex`. I would've gone for default methods (Java 8), but I have code that cannot be written in `interface`s (instance variables).

**Update**

Please note that `Index` has default post-construction functionality that is inherited in the other classes; this post-construction functionality *must* be executed once. Composition will force it to be executed twice at least, which makes composition an unviable solution to me.

**End Update**

I cannot find any non-redundant ways around this.

Any ideas?

Comment: I understand that `SubIndex` should inherit functionality from both classes and they can be easily inherited with some nested classes. What type should `SubIndex` derive from?

Comment: It derives from both `AbstractSubIndex` as well as `RootIndex`. Both classes has functionality that is needed to construct `SubIndex`.

Comment: I saw you needed to provide both functionalities inside `SubIndex`, but I was asking from the compiler's *typing* perspective. It still has to have a type. It can't act as types `A` *and* `B` simultaneously unless at most one of them is a class, but you know that.

Comment: Sorry, I misunderstood your question :) . Logically it is an `AbstractSubIndex`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, so from what I understand I think the following may cut it. Assume a simplified scenario with your `Index` class as

```
abstract class Index {

    public Index() {
        // your code here
        // ...

        postConstruct();
    }

    void postConstruct() {
        // your post construction stuff
    }

    // assumed just one abstract method, may be a thousand like it
    abstract void foo(); 
}
```

and your derived types as

```
class RootIndex extends Index {
    // ...

    @Override
    void foo() {
        // your stuff
    }

    public void bar() {
        // your additional stuff
    }
}
```

and

```
abstract class AbstractIndex extends Index {
    // ...
}
```

The way I would do it would be something like this. Create an interface that exposes the signatures of the *additional* functionality of `RootIndex`:

```
interface AdditionalFunctionalityInterface {
    void bar();
}
```

and make `RootIndex` implement it. Then I'd work around your once-postConstruct thing as below:

```
class SubIndex extends AbstractIndex implements AdditionalFunctionalityInterface {

    private class AuxRootIndex extends RootIndex {
        @Override
        void postConstruct() {
            // DON'T do what super.postConstruct() does
            // might as well be empty if you wish
        }
    }

    // composition
    private AuxRootIndex myRootIndex;

    @Override
    void foo() {
        // your stuff

        // a little bit unclear here, you can keep the one from
        // AbstractIndex or the one from RootIndex if you want
        myRootIndex.foo();
    }


    @Override
    public void bar() {
        myRootIndex.bar();
    }
}
```

Unless there are other conditions and contstraints, the above should do the trick, I hope. Your code may not have the same format as above, but you can bring it to this form by extracting additional code into separate methods.

Answer (score 1):

This workaround, strangely enough for me, is based on composition - thanks to @kinga93 and @AlexR's advice and a from-scratch aspect-oriented-like design -, but with more tweaking in the original code of the base classes, which is something I tried my best to avoid.

*Please note that I already marked @webuster's solution as the accepted solution, because it is simpler, and to-the-point gets the job done. I'm posting this because that is the one I went with in the end, as it makes more sense to me from a design point-of-view, and also in case someone needs it.*

1. I took the code that is not based on `Index` from `RootIndex`, and wrapped it in a class `ParentBehaviour`, and added a reference in its place.
2. I did the same in `AbstractSubIndex`, taking the code that is not based on `Index`, and wrapping it in another class `ChildBehavior`, and adding a reference in its place.
3. I used composition in `SubIndex`, with references from both `ParentBehavior` and `ChildBehavior`, while inheriting from `AbstractSubIndex`.
4. I used composition once again in `KPI`, inheriting from `AbstractSubIndex`, and in the same time having a reference from `ChildBehavior`.

The final code is something like this:

```
class ParentBehavior {
    // functionality that exists in RootIndex and SubIndex, which does not
    // depend on Index.
}

class ChildBehavior {
    // functionality that exists in SubIndex and KPI, which does not depend
    // on Index.
}

abstract class Index {
    // contains post-construction code.
    void foo();
}

class RootIndex extends Index {
    ParentBehavior parentBehavior;
}

abstract class AbstractSubIndex extends Index {
    // shared code between SubIndex and KPI
    ChildBehavior childBehavior;
}

class SubIndex extends AbstractSubIndex {
    ParentBehavior parentBehavior;
}

class KPI extends AbstractSubIndex {
    // unique functionality for KPI
}
```

That way, `SubIndex` and `KPI` inherit the basic functionality of `Index` from `AbstractSubIndex`, and thus inherit the post-construct functionality required from `Index` without repetition, while having only the functionality they needed from the base classes (through `ParentBehavior` and `ChildBehavior`).

Comment: That's exactly what I was going to post. Simple composition isn't the answer here, decorators are.

Comment: You know, I heard about decorators before, but never thought that this was it. I do need to revise design patterns -_- . Thanks for the tip. :)

Answer (score 0):

The standard way to solve such problems is delegation.

Define interfaces and their hierarchy as you need. Define concrete classes. When class A and class B that belong to different inheritance branches should share functionality implement it in class C and call methods of C from A and B.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but it's a little bit unclear to me. I think you mean that I use composition, which cannot work for me. Please check the updated section in the question.

Comment: Default post construction logic of `Index` must run once per instance, per sub class or once during the application life time?

Comment: Once per instance of class/subclass.

Answer (score 0):

Use composition instead of inheritance. Declare a field for AbstractIndex or RootIndex (or even two fields) inside your class.

Comment: There was something that I forgot to write in the question, which makes this solution unviable to me. There is default post-construction functionality in Index, which is inherited in both RootIndex as well as AbstractSubIndex. Composition will execute this functionality at least twice in all the cases you mentioned. Sorry that I didn't mention this part earlier; Updating now.